# Android Data binding for child class

Tags: android, data-binding, parent-child

I have to classes:

```
public class Product {
  private int id;
  private String title;
  .............
  .............
}
```

Other class is like below:

```
public class CatalogItem extends Product {
   private int price;
   private String[] colors;
   .............
   .............
}
```

In the layout, I want to access the all the properties of both child and parent classes.

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="catalogItem "
            type="com.appdemo.db.entity.CatalogItem" />
   </data>
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productIdTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{((com.appdemo.db.entity.Product) catalogItem).id}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
     ..................
     ..................
</layout>
```

But in the case of data binding, it failed to access the properties of parent class. What is the proper way to access the properties of parent class?

Comment: You can do it easily programatically (dynamically) instead? Is it possible? Design the pattern in xml and then add your items dynamically in Java I mean.

Comment: Why should I set each properties separately, then what is the use of Data Binding, @Fatmajk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your issue is your accessors are not public and labeled as @Bindable as you did the type casting, which is good, but if you are posting Pseduo code and are still stuck. I'll let you know what I ran into.

I found the same issue, and hit my head against the wall for several hours on this. I eventually found a post where someone talked about type casting in xml. I was prepared to pass in the child class and the parent class as in declare them both, and just set them both in the constructor to the same object. This is an option, just not an elegant one.

First the problem
xml data binding is not smart enough to crawl base classes yet with data class creations at compile time for the xml. This is a short coming, hopefully they will resolve soon. If someone reads this after they have fixed this issue, feel free to update the post ;).

So now for the solutions
Basically you have two options.

**OPTION 1**

You can declare both variables in your xml like this:

```
 <data>
    <variable name="parentPropertyModel" type="com.mypath.BaseModel"/>
    <variable name="childPropertyModel" type="com.mypath.ChildModel"/>
</data>
```

Then in your onCreate you would use set both.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_myscreen)
    mBinding.childPropertyModel = mSelectedObject
    mBinding.parentPropertyModel = mSelectedObject
}
```

Then of course you use the one you need for the property you are touching.

```
android:text="@{childPropertyModel.fieldInChild}"
android:hint="@{parentPropertyModel.fieldInParent}"
```

Now I don't know about you, but I don't like this as it gives the illusion of two distinct objects to future developers and can be confusing if you don't name them really well. So I went with option 2.

**OPTION 2**

Type casting, I gave it a shot and it worked :). You won't get intellisense, so you just have to know what you are typing, but it works I assure you.

Declare your variable like before.

```
<data>
     <variable name="classModel" type="com.mypath.ChildModel"/>
</data>
```

Then set it in your onCreate just like before, but only one object now.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_myscreen)
        mBinding.classModel = mSelectedObject
 }
```

then use it as needed with casting like this fully qualified path.

```
android:text="@{classModel.fieldInChild}"
android:hint="@{((com.mypath.BaseModel)classModel).fieldInParent}"
```

that's it, not the prettiest thing you've ever seen I'm sure, but it works.

I hope this saves someone out there the hours of headache that I endured figuring it out lol.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

make product class in id as public and give data and bind into xml.

```
public int id;
```

in xml

```
 android:text="@{catalogItem.id}"
```

Comment: this is the solution.Exactly right.if you want two way binding you can
do
android:text="@={catalogItem.id}"

Answer (score 0):

No such problem to access any properties, it not all related to their access modifier, it only needs proper getter method which can be accessed from Binding class. As `id` is int, its only needs String converter.

Answer (score -1):

Make the Parent class's fields protected. Only protected or public fields can be accessed by the child class.

```
protected int id;
```